# Django - Mysql Integrity error 1048, “Column 'id_fleet_id' cannot be null” while getting data from ajax

Tags: mysql, django

### Forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'post-text',  'placeholder': 'Say something...'}))
        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = ['text']
```

### Views.py

```
def create_post(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        post_text = request.POST.get('the_post')

        response_data = {}

        post = Post(text=post_text, author=request.user)

        post.save()

        response_data['result'] = 'Create post successful!'

        response_data['postpk'] = post.pk

        response_data['text'] = post.text

        response_data['created'] = post.created.strftime('%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p')

        response_data['author'] = post.author.username

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

### Main.js

```
$(function() {


    $('#post-form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("form submitted!")  
    });


    function create_post() {
        console.log("create post is working!") 
            url : "create_post/",
            type : "POST", 
            data : { the_post : $('#post-text').val() },
            success : function(json) {
                $('#post-text').val(''); 
                console.log(json); 
                $("#talk").prepend("<li><strong>"+json.text+"</strong> - <em> "+json.author+"</em> - <span> "+json.created+
                    "</span> - <a id='delete-post-"+json.postpk+"'>delete me</a></li>");
                console.log("success"); 
            },
            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                    " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); 
                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); 
            }
        /*});*/
    };


    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    /*
    The functions below will create a header with csrftoken
    */

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    function sameOrigin(url) {
        var host = document.location.host; 
        var protocol = document.location.protocol;
        var sr_origin = '//' + host;
        var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
        return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
            (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
            !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {

                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

### HTML

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/SIrNqv8h6QGKDuNoLGA4iret+kyesCkHGzVUUV0shc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<br><br>
<div class="row white">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <a href="/logout" class="right">Logout</a>
        <h2>Hi, {{request.user.username}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row white">
    <div class="columns large-12">
        <form method="POST" id="post-form" action="/create_post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="fieldWrapper" id="the_post">
                {{ form.text }}
            </div>
            <div id="results"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="Post" class="tiny button">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- The feed -->
<div class="row white">
    <div class="columns large-12">
        <ul id="talk">
            {% for post in all_posts %}
                <li>
                    <strong>{{ post.text }}</strong> 
                    <em>{{ post.author }}</em> -
                    <span>{{ post.created }}</span> 
                    <!-- <a id='delete-post-{{post.id}}'>delete me</a> -->
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="../static/js/main.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of reams of code

Comment: The error you're getting relates to putting data into a database, not getting it out

Comment: Please, don't spam tag your questions